# Create table where name contains a variable

Tags: sql-server, sqlparameter

It there a way to create a table in SQL Server 2016 containing a variable in the name without using code like this?

```
SET @SQL = 'Create table dbo.tblTest_' + @table + ' ...'
EXEC @SQL
```

We have existing stored procedures where we create tons of temp tables. I got the task to create tools that would allow the new developers to troubleshoot that big process in an easier way when we have issues with data, so I would like to be able to pass a parameters that will add the service request number to the temporary table name.

Is that clear enough ?

Here is an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    StartingOperatingEntityNumber, 
    CAST(0 AS INT) AS StartingOperatingId, 
    OperatingEntityNumber, ParentId, StructureLevel, 
    CAST(0 AS INT) AS CollectionEntityId
INTO 
    Temp.tblCEProcessingTempAllAncestors_WIT19101
FROM 
    AllParents a
    
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TempAllAncestors_StartingOperatingEntityNumber] 
ON Temp.tblCEProcessingTempAllAncestors_WIT19101
    ([StartingOperatingEntityNumber] ASC)
             WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                   SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                   DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TempAllAncestors_ParentId_StructureLevel] 
ON Temp.tblCEProcessingTempAllAncestors_WIT19101
    ([StructureLevel] DESC, [ParentId] ASC)
             WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                   SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                   DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

You can see that I add the WIT number to each temporary table.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    StartingOperatingEntityNumber, 
    CAST(0 AS INT) AS StartingOperatingId, 
    OperatingEntityNumber, ParentId, StructureLevel, 
    CAST(0 AS INT) AS CollectionEntityId
INTO 
    Temp.tblCEProcessingTempAllAncestors_@WIT
FROM 
    AllParents a
    
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TempAllAncestors_StartingOperatingEntityNumber] 
ON Temp.tblCEProcessingTempAllAncestors_@WIT
    ([StartingOperatingEntityNumber] ASC)
              WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TempAllAncestors_ParentId_StructureLevel] 
ON Temp.tblCEProcessingTempAllAncestors_@WIT
    ([StructureLevel] DESC, [ParentId] ASC)
              WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But it obviously didn't work....

Is there a fast and easy way to do this ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Mylene

Comment: no there is no way rather than dynamic sql

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I agree with Ehsan. This requires the use of dynamic SQL. Is there a particular reason you're against using that? (Yes, it is more complicated, but pretty much the only way you can dynamically influence the names of objects like you're trying to do)

Comment: That's what I thought !!  
Unfortunately, we are talking about more than 50 stored proc that would need to be adjusted in a very short period of time.  Oh well ! Thank you guys for the fast answer :-)